# How to compute sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-sum

How to compute sum of the form
$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty n \exp (- a n^2), a > 0$; as a function of $a$?

Can the result be described by a known function?

If not, what is the best approximation?

Comment: Maple, Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha gave no closed-form solution.